# Error while loading custom package?

Tags: r, statistics

Operating system: Ubuntu 12.04
R: 2.15.3

I am trying to load a custom R package that someone sent me. I have installed all the dependencies using

```
> intall.packages()
```

and I have installed the new package using

```
> $ sudo R CMD INSTALL -l /usr/lib/R/library/ CompModSA_1.5.tar.gz.
```

When I try and load the package in R,

```
> load(CompModSA)
```

I get the error:

```
> Error in load(CompModSA) : object 'CompModSA' not found.
```

I checked my `.libPaths()` and `/usr/lib/R/library` is the first directory. I tried searching and found some information about the NAMESPACE file, but haven't been able to figure out if there is something special about the NAMESPACE of this package, it contains

```
> exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
```

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Use `library(CompModSA)`. Type `?load` to see what that function does.

Comment: I'm just wondering how somebody knows to check .libPaths() but doesn't realize that you use `library` to load a package.  Was this just a typo on the OP's part?

Comment: Dason: This is my first time using R. I did some searching to determine where I should install the packages to ensure R finds them (similar for many programs). Upon this, I found the command .libPaths(). I was trying to use load() because my friend (the one who built the package), told me to use it. I figured since he was an experienced R user, he gave me the right command. I apologize if this was a dumb question (seem as thought it was as it's -2 already), but everything is working great now, so I'm happy.

Comment: Very bad idea to use `sudo R CMD INSTALL -l /usr/lib/R/library/ CompModSA_1.5.tar.gz` and to override via `-l` --- `/usr/local/` is called local for a reason. Your personal packages should go there, and the default behaviour is fine.

Comment: By the way, the original question is answered in the R-FAQ.